# Is there any way to connect to a second (MySQL) database in a Kernel Base test?

Tags: 8, database, testing

Right now I have configured this environment variable in my phpunit.xml to connect to a Drupal database in a SQLite file:

```
<env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="sqlite://localhost//Users/jepster/Dev/my-project/project/docroot/sites/default/files/db.sqlite"/>
```

This works fine. But can I also connect to a second database like I am doing in the settings.php?

```
$databases['second-database']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'second-database',
  'username' => 'second-database',
  'password' => 'second-database',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Currently my Kernel Base Test fails with the following error:

> The specified database connection is not defined: second-database

That's because I want to connect to my database from a service constructor:

```
  public function __construct() {
    $this->database = Database::getConnection('default','second-database');
  }
```

I have been digging in the Drupal core Kernel Base Tests ("core" folder), but I could not find a way there.

Answer (score 5):

I have figured it out. The setUp() method in my Kernel Base Test must look like that:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $databases['second-database']['default'] = array(
        'database' => 'second-database',
        'username' => 'second-database',
        'password' => 'second-database',
        'prefix' => '',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
        'driver' => 'mysql',
    );
    Database::setMultipleConnectionInfo(
        $databases
    );
}
```